# How to indent a text block in Context, either Nested or with Multiple Levels?

Tags: indentation, context

Using Context, I want to be able to indent text blocks from the left, and which go all the way to the normal right margin. It looks like a context equivalent of using adjustwidth from the Latex changepage package is what I need. My understanding is that a Latex package doesn't work with Context.

I tried to get framedtext to do this by turning the frame off, but it leaves more-then-usual amount of space between lines, and I think it applies its indentations on both the left and the right.

My goal is to create outlines with different/nested levels of indention, but I don't need the specific solution of nested indentations. I'm fine with applying a specific level of indentation to each line as required. I also don't want any automated line labeling that might come with a specific outline solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\startnarrower[left]`:

```tex
\starttext
    \samplefile{knuth}

    \startnarrower[left]
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \startnarrower[left]
            \samplefile{knuth}
        \stopnarrower
    \stopnarrower
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.